# RabbitMQ Queue Management

Tags: spring-boot, jakarta-ee, rabbitmq

I am currently implementing RabbitMQ queues for processing some business logic.
Here I have to push the Objects to queue and process them. Here i have 5K objects, my plan is  i want to create 5 queues and limit each queue to take 1k objects and process them, so that 5k objects will be populated to 5 queues and process will be done simultaneously. **Here need your suggestion how i can limit the max allow objects per queue and how i can tell the system/manage the population of next 1k objects to next queue., Any one can suggest me the best mechanism/way to achieve this.**

Thanks,
Sudheer

Answer (score 1):

You can check the documentation to see how to set [maximum size to a queue](https://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html).

By default, if the queue is full, new messages will be dropped. Since RabbitMQ `3.7.0` you can configure the broker [notify the publisher](https://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html#overflow-behaviour) when a queue overflows.

In this way, you can let the publisher wait until there is new space in the queue.

Comment: Is there any way we can send the object to other queue once the first queue is full? Or is there any thing like Load balancer to distribute the objects between different queues in round robin way (in my case 5 queues).?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to achieve that. Why are you planning to split the queue into 5 of them? Why simply not a 25K sized queue?

Comment: I want to reduce the processing times. If i am using only one queue suppose i am pushing 1k objects . The listener will pick and do processing take 10 mins then it will take more time for 1K objects. If i maintain 5 queues and 5 listeners for those queues and i can do processing parallel and i can reduce the processing time.

Comment: You can attach as many consumers as you want to the same queue. RabbitMQ will evenly distribute the tasks to the attached consumers. Just make sure each listener uses a dedicated `channel`.